# Detect Edge browser using java

Tags: java, web, playframework, microsoft-edge

I want to detect Edge browser(windows 10) using `UserAgentFamily` enum class(package net.sf.uadetector). There is no option related to Edge broswer.

Such as `UserAgentFamily`.IE and `UserAgentFamily`. SAFARI for detecting IE and safari browser. How will I detect edge broswer using UserFamily.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use another library that has the features you want. For example, [user-agent-utils](http://www.bitwalker.eu/software/user-agent-utils).

If you really want to use the library you are using now, you can try to build a newer version, but it seems it has [some bugs](https://github.com/before/uadetector/issues/131) relating Edge